# How do you take a part of a variable out, change it, then put it back in?

Tags: php

I am wondering is there a way to take a string out of a variable, edit it then put it back into the variable.
for example:

```
$var = "hey hey how are you @Damien today?"
```

What I'd want to do is take out @Damien (as I'm coding a tagging system), run it through a SQL query then
turn `@Damien` into (for example) `<a href="#/profile?id=15">Damien</a>`

Then put that link back in place where @Damien was, so it'd be
`$var = "hey hey how are you <a href="#/profile?id=15">Damien</a> today?"`

Comment: yes. "take it out" = search for a string that matches some criteria (starts with @) -> preg_match(). Do with that whatever you need (search in db, ...) then do a preg_replace() to replace @Damien with the new value.

Comment: as it is now your question will be tagged (pun intended) as "too broad", because there is no attempt shown of solving your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [preg_replace_callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php). Something like this should work:

```
<?php
$var = "hey hey how are you @Damien today?";
$replaced_text = preg_replace_callback('/@[A-Za-z]+/', function($match) {
    // run query using $match variable and form your replacement
    return "<a href='link'>$match</a>";
}, $var);

echo $replaced_text;
```

Comment: perfect! thanks a bunch